# Does distributive property `(a+b)c = ac+bc` apply to python type hinting as well?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

For Python ≤ 3.8:

```
from typing import Union, Tuple, List
```

Is

```
Union[List[str], List[Tuple[str, str]]]
```

the same as

```
List[Union[str, Tuple[str, str]]]
```

Comment: They are not logically the same. The first is either a list of strings or a list of tuples; the second is a list that can contain strings and tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not logically the same. The first is either a list of strings or a list of tuples; the second is a list that can contain strings and tuples.

`['alpha', ('beta', 'gamma')]` is valid as `List[Union[str, Tuple[str, str]]]`, but not valid as `Union[List[str], List[Tuple[str, str]]]`.